# Estimating accuracy with (x == y).mean() - How does it work?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

May I ask how can this function count the accuracy?

```
def accuracy_score(truth, pred):
    if len(truth) == len(pred): 
        return "Predictions have an accuracy of {:.2f}%.".format((truth == pred).mean()*100)
    else:
        return "Number of predictions does not match number of outcomes!"

# Test the 'accuracy_score' function predictions = pd.Series(np.ones(5, dtype = int)) print accuracy_score(outcomes[:5], predictions)
```

---

I have not idea why

```
(truth == pred).mean()
```

can count any number, doesn't it just judge if it's True and False?

Comment: Not sure but it is probably changing booleans to list of 1s and 0s and then getting the mean of those

Comment: It appears that `truth` and `pred` are two numpy arrays. If that's the case, `truth == pred` creates a new array in which a `1` indicates that the corresponding values in `truth` and `pred` are equal, and `0` otherwise. Then, taking the mean of all of that tells you how accurate your predictor/classifier is, on average

Answer (score 5):

`truth` is an array of labels. `pred` is an array of predictions by the model. In an ideal situation, `truth` must equal `pred`. However, practically, there will be errors in the model's prediction. Thus, the concept of accuracy which measures how many data points the model predicted correctly.

Assuming these are numpy arrays,

```
truth == pred
```

Returns a boolean array of `True` and `False`. For example:

```
In [668]: x = np.array([1, 1, 2, 1])

In [669]: y = np.array([1, 2, 1, 1])

In [670]: x == y
Out[670]: array([ True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Now, `.mean()` will count the number of `True` and divide by the total size, giving the accuracy:

```
In [671]: (x == y).mean()
Out[671]: 0.5
```

Which is the same as:

```
In [672]: (x == y).sum() / len(x == y)
Out[672]: 0.5
```

And,

```
In [673]: (x == y).sum()
Out[673]: 2
```

Which is the number of `True` vals in the boolean array.

Answer (score 4):

I assume the `truth` and `pred` are NumPy arrays or subclasses - and for NumPy functions `True` and `False` are interpreted as `1` or `0`.

So `mean` just adds the number of occurrences where `truth` is equal to `pred` and divides it by the number of elements.

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([True, False, True])
>>> arr.sum()
2
>>> arr.mean()
0.66666666666666663
```